# dockerize does not delay the container initialization

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I am now preparing the images for my project. I use `dockerize` to control my initialization. I am not sure that hardcode the `IP` address given by docker is way to go or not?

**Problem:**
`backend` does not wait until the `database` finish initialization first.

Terminal says

```
backend_1      | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
backend_1      |        Is the server running on host "sakahama_db" (172.21.0.2) and accepting
backend_1      |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Here are my files:**

devdb.dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.5

# Install hstore extension
COPY ./Dockerfiles/hstore.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql-static/data
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql-static/data
```

hstore.sql

```
create extension hstore;
```

backend.dockerfile

```
FROM python:2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget

ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.2.0
RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements ./requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements/local.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD echo "dockerize"
CMD ["dockerize", "-wait", "tcp://sakahama_db:5432"]

CMD echo "migrate"
CMD ["python", "sakahama/manage.py", "migrate"]

CMD echo "runserver"
CMD ["python", "sakahama/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/backend.dockerfile
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:password@sakahama_db:5432/sakahama
      REDISCLOUD_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
    links:
      - sakahama_db
    ports:
      - "9000:8000"

  sakahama_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/devdb.dockerfile
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: sakahama
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

**Question:** How to use `dockerize` properly?

**Update:**
I had tried temporary solution like this. But it does not work
`backend-entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "dockerize"
dockerize -wait tcp://sakahama_db:5432

echo "migrate"
python sakahama/manage.py migrate

echo "runserver"
python sakahama/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and docker-compose.yml:
I add one line
`command: ["sh", "Dockerfiles/backend-entrypoint.sh"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Postgres container is up it starts to receive tcp packages you send with the command: `dockerize -wait tcp://sakahama_db:5432` , but it does not mean that the Postgres service is ready. It takes some time to load, to set up users, passwords, create the db or load the databases and make all the grants needed.

I had a similar issue with Flask and MySQL, I created an sh script like you did and inside it I made a simple loop to check if the service was up before starting the Flask application

I am not a shell script Senior but here follow the script:

```
# testing if databas is up
mysql -h database -uroot -proot databasename
ISDBUP=$?
while [[ $ISDBUP != "0" ]]; do
    echo "database is not up yet, waiting for 5 seconds"
    sleep 5;
    mysql -h database -uroot -proot databasename -e "SELECT 1;";
    ISDBUP=$?
done

# starting the application
python server.py app
```

Comment: I accept your answer. Your first sentence give me exactly the clue. I have to set timeout to 120s. Then it works :)